# Header files not found when porting from AIX to linux

Tags: linux, migration, aix, porting

I am got source files from an application on IBM AIX and I am trying to build them on Linux. However I am getting compilation errors header file not found.

When compiled source from AIX on Linux got error these headers not found:

```
usersec.h
userpw.h 
sys/mode.h
standards.h
```

After I Googled I realized they are headers (`/usr/include/usersec.h`) for user management (user authentication and pwd verification etc) funtions on AIX.

As there is no equivalent header on Linux, I like to know what is best practice to port these functions? What are there equivalent headers/functions on Linux.

As there is not much information I found on net hence posting it here as I am badly stuck. Thank you.

Update: Details of functions being migrated are mentioned in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062930/migrating-aix-specific-c-function-calls-to-linux)

Comment: You don't port headers *per se*; you port functions and behaviors. I think you need to list the functions you are using on AIX and then describe their behavior. For user management on Linux, there are functions to lookup users and passwords in the user database. For example, see the [`getpwnam(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam) and [`passwd(5)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd).

Comment: @jww: Yes I got the point. Sure I'll provide what functions have been used from these headers. Will be needing some time to update the question. Thanks for you directions.

Comment: I don't think this is even standardized on Linux, it's probably dependent on the distribution.

Comment: @Barmar - `getpwnam` and and friends claim to conform to SVr4, 4.3BSD and POSIX.1-2001. There is probably some portability available, depending on runtime library version and compiler options. Posix usually starts breaking in C++ above C++03. It may take some jiggering to get the program to work with `libstdc++` and  `-std=c++11`. I don't know how LLVM `libc++` or Musl react.

Comment: @jww I don't know precisely what's in the functions he's using, but I presumed they're higher level APIs than things like `getpwnam`, doing things like `useradd`.

Comment: @Barmar: I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062930/migrating-aix-specific-c-function-calls-to-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1) having details of functions.