# Migrating AIX specific C function calls to Linux

Tags: c, linux, migration, aix, porting

I have got source files from an application on IBM AIX and I am trying to build them on Linux. However, header files named `usersec.h`and `userpw.h` which are there on AIX are not present on Linux. Hence, on Linux I am getting compiler error for these functions:

Declared in `usersec.h`

```
int     getuserattr (char *, char *, void *, int);
```

More info about `getuserattr` is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/getuserattr.htm)

Declared in `userpw.h`

```
struct userpw
{
        char    *upw_passwd;            /* user's passwd */
        unsigned int    upw_flags;      /* flags of restrictions */
        time_t  upw_lastupdate;         /* date of last passwd update */
        char    upw_name[PW_NAMELEN];   /* user's name */
};

struct userpw   *getuserpw (); 
int setpwdb ();  
int endpwdb ();
```

Please find more information: [getuserpw](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/getuserpw.htm), [setpwdb and endpwdb](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/beta/no/ssw_aix_72/s_bostechref/setpwdb.html)

If anyone knows how to write equivalent functions on Linux, it would be really great.

Comment: Do you have some more insights of what should the `userpw` struct contain, and of the expected behavior of `getuserattr()`, `getuserpw()`, `setpwdb()` and `endpwdb()`?

Comment: It is not possible to read a user's password on Linux, only the hash is stored.

Comment: [getspent()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getspnam.3.html) and friends are probably the closest equivalent for the pwdb stuff.

Comment: @StefOverflow Many thanks for comment. I've added links to documentation of those function.

Comment: Also see [Header files not found when porting from AIX to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57050832/608639)

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use [`getpwent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html), and its related functions.

> The `getpwent()` function returns a pointer to a structure containing
>          the broken-out fields of a record from the password database (e.g.,
>          the local password file `/etc/passwd`, NIS, and LDAP).  The first time
>          `getpwent()` is called, it returns the first entry; thereafter, it
>          returns successive entries.
>
> The `setpwent()` function rewinds to the beginning of the password
>          database.
>
> The `endpwent()` function is used to close the password database after
>          all processing has been performed.

If you want to get the password entry of a particular user, you can use [`getpwnam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) or one of its variants.

> The `getpwnam()` function returns a pointer to a structure containing
>          the broken-out fields of the record in the password database (e.g.,
>          the local password file `/etc/passwd`, NIS, and LDAP) that matches the
>          username *name*.